# cannot update row using Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm using the Python example at http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#update-row(s) nearly verbatim. The difference is I'm updating only one cell in one row. I can see the value change in the variable `row_a` but the row does not get updated in the Smartsheet itself.

Here is my code, which is nearly identical to the code posted in the API guide:

```
row_a = smartsheet.Sheets.get_row(sheetId, 916467282667396)
cell_a = row_a.get_column(5937660066850692)
cell_a.value = 'new value'
row_a.set_column(cell_a.column_id, cell_a)
smartsheet.Sheets.update_rows(sheetId, [row_a])
```

Seeing that the text 'new value' does not appear in the Smartsheet after running this code, I added the word **print** in front of the last line to see what is returned by the API call and this is the result (I added indentation for readability):

```
{
    "requestResponse": null, 
    "result": {
        "code": 1062, 
        "name": "InvalidRowLocationError", 
        "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem.", 
        "shouldRetry": false, 
        "message": "Invalid row location.", 
        "statusCode": 400
    }
}
```

How can I fix the `InvalidRowLocationError` and get my row update to be sent to the Smartsheet?

Comment: I just ran your code with my own sheet and row ids and it worked for me. The error code is a result of trying to move the row. Are you calling `move_rows` any where in your code?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to move a row. The code I posted is all of my code (except the import and setting of the sheetId constant). I'm totally baffled. I put print statements after every line of code to verify it's doing what I expect and everything behaves as expected until the "update_rows" command. I even ran the API calls manually with Postman and it works. Confirmed the SDK is supposed to work with Python 2.7.

Comment: Would you mind sending this question to api@smartsheet.com ? Our support team would like to work with you to reproduce the issue so that we can help you get moving again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two bugs associated with update_rows in the smartsheet-python-sdk version 1.0.1 but there is also a workaround. The error `InvalidRowLocationError` is encountered if you try to update a row where a cell is indented (see bug description at https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues/44). The error `NotEditableViaApiError` is encountered if you try to update a row where a cell contains formulas, links to other cells, system values, or Gantt values (see bug description at https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/issues/42).

These errors occur no matter which cell in the row you try to update because the smartsheet-python-sdk updates **an entire row**. It's important to note that the API works. So the workaround is to use the Python `requests` module to perform the actual update like this:

```
import requests
url = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/SHEETID/rows"
payload = "{\"id\": 6436521654937476, \"cells\": [{\"columnId\": 8276294740797316,\"value\": \"new value\"}]}" 
# headers omitted from here for privacy
headers = { YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY }
response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

In the sample above, the payload contains only the one cell that I wanted to update rather than the entire row. A more readable version of the payload is (a row object with only one cell):

```
{
  "id": 6436521654937476,
  "cells": [
    {
      "columnId": 8276294740797316,
      "value": "new value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue here is that the request requires you to use PUT instead of POST.
See: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#update-row(s)

Comment: The original question has to do with using the smartsheet-python-sdk. When using the Python SDK, things like PUT and POST are abstracted from the user, who instead calls a method.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to still use the sdk while only updating certain cells in a row where a given row has formulas and things blocking api updates which is related to the `NotEditableViaApiError`.

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    cell = row.get_column(column_id)
    cell.value = 'modified cell value'  # edit the cell locally

    # gather more cells and add to list of cells for row...

    # remove all cells in row and just add back the single cell or list of cells
    row.cells = [cell]
    print my_sheets.update_rows(sheet_id, [row])  # update sheet
```

There's still an api call per row for me being able to get things working, but at least there's a way around the issue of only updating certain cells for a given row.  This call will only update cells in the row's list and will leave others untouched.