# How to parse Smartsheet API 2.0 Python SDK error results?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to get the update_rows method working

(the answers here haven't helped yet:

[cannot update row using Smartsheet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364385/cannot-update-row-using-smartsheet-api)

)

and would like to capture and parse the results

```
results = smartsheet.Sheets.update_rows(test_sheet_id, [row])

print(results)
```

gives me this:

```
{"requestResponse": null, "result": {"shouldRetry": false, "name":
"InvalidRowLocationError", "code": 1062, "recommendation": "Do not retry
without fixing the problem.", "message": "Invalid row location.",
"statusCode": 400}}
```

Note that a success looks like this (snipped most of it):

```
{"resultCode": 0, "message": "SUCCESS", "version": 21, "result":
[{"discussions": [], "createdAt": null, "above": null, "modifiedAt": 
null, "columns": [], "toTop": null, "sheetId": null, "siblingId":
4800885606901636, "permalink": null, "id": 6067523002099588,
"accessLevel": null, "conditionalFormat": null, "attachments": [],
"cells": [{"columnType": null, "displayValue": null, "linksOutToCells":
null, "strict": true, "hyperlink": null, "formula": null, "format": null,
"conditionalFormat": null, "columnId": 7600931584927620, "linkInFromCell":
 null, "value": null}, {"columnType": null, "displayValue": null, "
... snip ...
```

This looks like a dictionary, but the keys, items, values aren't recognized.
Next it looks like json - but nothing I've tried (I don't know much about json yet) has worked either.

If I could get the *resultCode* from a success, that would be a start.
Better would be the value from *result*, but that appears to be a dictionary for a fail and a list for successes.

I'm confused. Any help appreciated.
I'm using Python 3.5, Smartsheet API 2.0 Python SDK

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
results = smartsheet.Sheets.update_rows(test_sheet_id, [row])
```

returns an *result* object from the **models\error_result.py** code of the SDK.

That object has two methods of interest and each property can be referenced like so:

```
print(results.result.code)
```

returns the code (1062 for example)

The two methods are *to_dict* and *to_json* which can be accessed and printed like so:

```
print(results.result.to_dict())
```

gives:

```
    {'shouldRetry': False, 'name': 'InvalidRowLocationError', 'code': 1062,
    'recommendation': 'Do not retry without fixing the problem.', 'message':
    'Invalid row location.', 'statusCode': 400}

my_dict = results.result.to_dict()
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

gives:

```
    shouldRetry False
    name InvalidRowLocationError
    code 1062
    recommendation Do not retry without fixing the problem.
    message Invalid row location.
    statusCode 400
```

and the *to_json* code

```
print(results.result.to_json())
```

gives

```
    {
        "shouldRetry": false,
        "name": "InvalidRowLocationError",
        "code": 1062,
        "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem.",
        "message": "Invalid row location.",
        "statusCode": 400
    }
```

and:

```
my_json = results.result.to_json()
my_dict = json.loads(my_json)
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

gives:

```
    shouldRetry False
    name InvalidRowLocationError
    code 1062
    recommendation Do not retry without fixing the problem.
    message Invalid row location.
    statusCode 400
```